# Do I need to va_end when an exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, exception, variadic-functions, printf

I have a logging framework based on `printf`-style formatting:

```
void Logger::debug(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    this->output(DebugLevel, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

If `Logger::output` throws, will the compiler unwind the stack properly, or do I need to add a try/catch block with `va_end(args)` in the catch clause? Can this be RAII'ed instead, or is `va_end` too magic for that? If possible, please include references to the standard.

Comment: "Can this be RAII'ed instead": no, `va_*` identifiers are macros.

Comment: Really better if you don't use such things in C++. They are extremely unsafe and definitely unnecessary.

Comment: I think that wherever you have `va_start()` you will have to use `va_end()` _inside the variadic function_. Note that try-catch will significantly decrease performance if you plan on logging a lot.

Answer (score 8):

No, they cannot. The reasoning that they cannot because they are macros is silly. Macros are usable from constructors and destructors without any issues. However, `va_start` and `va_end` have specific requirements that they must be called from the same function. Moving them to separate functions is invalid. C++ refers to the C standard, and the C standard says "Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function." (7.15.1) If you do call `va_end` from a helper class's destructor, it may work, or it may not. Since it doesn't  meet the requirements of the standard, the behaviour is undefined.

Edit: as for the other question, do you need `va_end` at all when an exception is thrown, a legitimate argument could be made that "invocation of the `va_end` macro" doesn't actually require that the code reach the point where you invoke that macro (since macro invocation is strictly a compile-time-only action), but it strongly suggests that you do need it. So yes, use `try`/`catch` if exceptions are a possibility. The C99 rationale briefly notes in its description of `va_copy` that `va_start` may allocate memory. (I know of no implementation where it actually does do so.) On such an implementation, `va_end` would then deallocate that memory, so skipping `va_end` would cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

No `va_start` and `va_end` are macros. So, they cannot be `RAII`'ed. Also, no special care is needed for exceptions.

Comment: Special care *is* needed for exceptions. Returning from the function after invoking `va_start` without a matching `va_end` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Undefined according to the standard, yes. But in >99% of actual implementations, `va_end` does nothing, and omitting it is harmless. You only need `va_end` if you care about the <1% of of super-obscure implementations for which it is actually necessary. Something undefined per the standard can still be defined per an implementation, and if it is defined the same in all the implementations you care about, in practice that is equivalent to the standard defining it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be RAII'ed using [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html), even though va_start/va_end are macro's.